# How can I resize the desktop work area using the SPI_SETWORKAREA flag?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winapi, pinvoke

I have been trying for quite a while now to resize the desktop work area (the area where windows get maximized). I have found the required API, but I can't seem to resize the work area. It does just nothing.

I use Windows 7 Ultimate x64 so I also tried compiling it in x64 'mode', and still no luck. Could someone give me a push in the right direction?

Here is what I got so far:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "SystemParametersInfoA")]
private static extern Int32 SystemParametersInfo(Int32 uAction, Int32 uParam, IntPtr lpvParam, Int32 fuWinIni);

private const Int32 SPIF_SENDWININICHANGE = 2;
private const Int32 SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE = 1;
private const Int32 SPIF_change = SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE | SPIF_SENDWININICHANGE;
private const Int32 SPI_SETWORKAREA = 47;
private const Int32 SPI_GETWORKAREA = 48;

public struct RECT
{
    public Int32 Left;
    public Int32 Right;
    public Int32 Top;
    public Int32 Bottom;
}

private static int SetWorkspace(RECT oRECT)
{
    IntPtr ptr = IntPtr.Zero;
    ptr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(oRECT));
    Marshal.StructureToPtr(oRECT, ptr, true);
    return SystemParametersInfo(SPI_SETWORKAREA, Marshal.SizeOf(oRECT), ptr, SPIF_change);
}
```

Comment: Why in the world are you calling the ASCII version of that function, instead of the wide version?

Comment: Try this : SystemParametersInfo( SPI_SETWORKAREA, 1, &NewRect, SPIF_SENDCHANGE );

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The following code should work just fine:

```
// 1. Change the function to call the Unicode variant, where applicable.
// 2. Ask the marshaller to alert you to any errors that occur.
// 3. Change the parameter types to make marshaling easier. 
[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
private static extern bool SystemParametersInfo(
                                                int uiAction,
                                                int uiParam,
                                                ref RECT pvParam,
                                                int fWinIni);

private const Int32 SPIF_SENDWININICHANGE = 2;
private const Int32 SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE = 1;
private const Int32 SPIF_change = SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE | SPIF_SENDWININICHANGE;
private const Int32 SPI_SETWORKAREA = 47;
private const Int32 SPI_GETWORKAREA = 48;

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct RECT
{
    public Int32 Left;
    public Int32 Top;   // top is before right in the native struct
    public Int32 Right;
    public Int32 Bottom;
}

private static bool SetWorkspace(RECT rect)
{
   // Since you've declared the P/Invoke function correctly, you don't need to
   // do the marshaling yourself manually. The .NET FW will take care of it.

   bool result = SystemParametersInfo(SPI_SETWORKAREA,
                                      IntPtr.Zero,
                                      ref RECT,
                                      SPIF_change);
   if (!result)
   {
       // Find out the error code
       MessageBox.Show("The last error was: " +
                       Marshal.GetLastWin32Error().ToString());
   }

   return result;
}
```

But I'm not really sure what you're trying to do. By default, the work area is the portion of the screen not obscured by the system taskbar or by application desktop toolbars. You're not going to be able to make it any larger than the area that's available on your screen (neat trick if you could, though!). Do your windows not already fill the entire screen when you maximize them?

And even on machines with multiple monitors, you can't set the working area to span multiple monitors. The [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724947.aspx) says that it's constrained to setting the working area of the monitor that contains the specified rectangle:

> In a system with multiple display monitors, the function sets the work area of the monitor that contains the specified rectangle.

Comment: Your code fixed it plus my RECT point was outside the screen. Thanks anyway!

Comment: @Cody Gray.
I am facing somewhat similar issue. I'm launching child 2nd application from my app, and in 2nd app I do SetParent(2ndAppHandle, 1stAppHandle). But now my 2nd app is restricted to 1st screen. I'm trying to set workspace area to 2nd screen;but as mentioned above it gives error as InvalidParameters. Can you please help me out with it???

Comment: @Akshay How does that have anything to do with this question or this answer?

Comment: @CodyGray I am trying to set workspace area of 2nd/child application to occupy 2 screens. Because when I move my 2nd application on second monitor by setting Window.Left > primaryMonitorWidth, it get cut off and not shown, as parent/1st application which launched it, has workspace area of only 1st screen.

Comment: Yeah, there are all kinds of problems with using SetParent across processes. I've never actually tried to do what you're describing. If you want me or someone else to investigate, you should ask a new question about it. Include a [mcve] that reproduces your problem. You do know that SPI_SETWORKAREA is a *global* setting, right? It doesn't take a window handle or process handle as a parameter, so there's no way it could be specific to either. The name of the function is a clue: *system parameters*. @akshay