# Facebook messenger application like docking

Tags: java, windows, facebook, sidebar, dock

The Facebook messenger for windows 7 docks on the side of the screen and does not allow any other application to go on top of it.For example when i maximize another window , it does not cover the Facebook window.

How can i do this in java.
So far i can dock my window to the right, i set it undecorated and also always on top. But i want it to be like Facebook messenger so other windows can go maximize but only where it meets my docked window.

Here is a slimier question 
http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/278553-facebook-messenger-application-sidebar-like-docking-with-swing/

Comment: I believe you have to adjust the work area in order to accomplish this. [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6267206/how-can-i-resize-the-desktop-work-area-using-the-spi-setworkarea-flag) might help you in the right direction.

Comment: This might be even better actually: [Creating an Application Desktop Toolbar](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/134206)

Comment: Yes but none of them are in java

Comment: I don't think you can do this with "pure Java"

Comment: yes i am still searching. no one seems to want to do something like that but it is amazing what they have done. unlucky me i guess