# Windows 10 not responding to uiAction 47 (SPI_SETWORKAREA) for user32.dll's SystemParametersInfo(uAction, uParam, lpvParam, fuWinIni)

Tags: windows-10, user32

Does anyone have any information on why Windows 10 no longer allows you to set a custom WorkArea using SystemParametersInfo? I was using this to reserve screen space for dock/bar applications. Anyone had any luck getting it working?

For reference the code on this question works to set a custom work area In Windows 8.1, 8, 7, and XP, but no longer works on Windows 10. 
[How can I resize the desktop work area using the SPI_SETWORKAREA flag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6267206/how-can-i-resize-the-desktop-work-area-using-the-spi-setworkarea-flag#)

My only alternative options seem to be using SHAppBarMessage (not preferable as it does not allow modifying form opacity to my knowledge), or using SetWindowsHookEx with WH_CALLWNDPROC, but that seems to require .dll injection for external processes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar issue, an old program that correctly set the work area in Windows 7 stopped working in Windows 10.

What worked for me was changing the 'fWinIni' argument (the last argument) from SPIF_CHANGE to SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE.

So, what previously worked but doesn't anymore:

```
private const uint SPIF_SENDWININICHANGE = 2;
private const uint SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE = 1;
private const uint SPIF_CHANGE = SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE | SPIF_SENDWININICHANGE;
SystemParametersInfo(SPI_SETWORKAREA, 0, ref rect, SPIF_CHANGE);
```

What works correctly now:

```
private const uint SPIF_SENDWININICHANGE = 2;
private const uint SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE = 1;
private const uint SPIF_CHANGE = SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE | SPIF_SENDWININICHANGE;
SystemParametersInfo(SPI_SETWORKAREA, 0, ref rect, SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE);
```

Hopefully this works for you as well.

Comment: Thank you!! This worked for me also, I've marked this as correct. The only difference I notice is it does not appear to also keep desktop icons within those borders as it did on Windows 7 and 8.

Comment: The other thing I've noticed with this is that the Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea now doesn't reflect the values of the adjusted working area so i'm having difficulty monitoring if an adjustment has occurred.

Answer (score 0):

Just as an FYI  when I used just the SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE only in the SystemParameterInfo send I had issues where the Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkArea wasn't recognising the system changes and was permanently set to the full bounds of the screen.

SystemParametersInfo(SPI_SETWORKAREA, 0, ref rect, 0);

Worked better for me in Windows 10 and correctly set the workarea variables.